# Can't seem to place While loop in the right place - noob Java Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, loops, while-loop

First off, apologies, I'm new to all this and I'm struggling with Android / Java. Ive spent days looking stuff up and I KNOW I'm doing something stupid but would appreciate someone to tell me why / where I'm going wrong.

The app is a simple quiz, puts a picture up, use a spinner to select the answer, press a button to submit, get a toast message to verify and add a score. I know the code is horrendous and a hack but I lack the knowledge to do it more elegantly (part of the reason I'm here). I am trying to place a `while` loop, using the variable `sflags` that will be counting up from 0 to 26. When I place it, I can never seem to place it correctly so it works. I suspect some of the code gets broken when I try and wrap it.

Here's the (terrible) code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
   private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

   private EditText mName;
   private EditText mEmail;
   private ListView countrieslist;
   private String comments;
   private int score = 0;
   private int sflags = 0;
   private String emailok;
   private String answer;
   private String flags;
   private Spinner spinnerct;
   private Object countries;

   // private AdapterView<ListAdapter> spinnerct;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.flagnames);
      mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
      mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

      mEmail.addTextChangedListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      emailok = s.toString();
      String sub_but = getString(R.string.sub_but);

      boolean valid = emailok.length() > 0 && 
                      emailok.toLowerCase().indexOf(sub_but) == -1;

      View view = findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


      boolean isVisible = view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
      if (isVisible == valid) {
         // No animation required if both values are true or both values are
         // false
         return;
      }
      Animation anim;

      if (valid) {
         view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         // Create a new animation object
         anim = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(this, true);
      } else {
         // Create a new animation object
         anim = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
         view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
      // Tell the view it's time to start animating
      view.startAnimation(anim);
   }

   public void thequiz(View view) {

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

      Toast.makeText(
         this.getApplicationContext(),
         "Thanks  ! Now try to identify the flags of these European Countries!",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG
      ).show();

      sflags = 0;
      score = 0;

      // LinearLayOut Setup
      LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
      linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

      linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

      // ImageView Setup
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

      // Constructing the filename using "flag" + the item number from
      // variable loop
      // using GetIndentifier to return resource to a string

      // while loop start here?
      //while (sflags<27){

      // display correct flag
      imageView.setImageResource( 
         this.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/flag" + sflags, null, this.getPackageName())
      );
      // setting image position
      imageView.setLayoutParams(
         new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
      );
      // =================================================================
      // creating spinner object
      final Spinner spinnerct = new Spinner(this);
      // Now to populate spinner with contents of array flagnames[]
      ArrayAdapter<String> spinnercountry = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.flagnames)
      );
      spinnerct.setAdapter(spinnercountry);
      // creating button
      Button myButton = new Button(this);
      myButton.setText("Submit Answer");
      myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(250, 200, 250));
      // ===================================================================
      // adding view to layout
      linearLayout.addView(imageView);
      linearLayout.addView(spinnerct);
      linearLayout.addView(myButton);
      // Show layout
      setContentView(linearLayout);

      // OnclickListener to see when button is clicked
      //=========================================================
      myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            answer = spinnerct.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(
               MainActivity.this, 
               "You selected " + answer, 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
            // now check the answer is right by calling checkanswer()
            //=======================================================
            boolean tester = false;
            checkanswer(tester); // jumps to procedure, returns boolean

            if (tester = true) {
               score = score + 1;
               Toast.makeText(
                  MainActivity.this, 
                  "Well done, correct answer! Your Score is " + score + " out of 27", 
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG
               ).show();
            }
            //========================================================
            if (tester != true) {
               Toast.makeText(
                  MainActivity.this,
                  "Sorry wrong answer! ",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
               ).show();
            }
            //=========================================================
            sflags = sflags + 1;
         }
      });
   };


   // sendSMS();
   // sendEmail();
   // }

   //=======================================================
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   //========================================================
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   //=========================================================
   public void checkanswer(boolean Isitright) {
      if (sflags == 0 && answer == "Estonia") {
         Isitright = true;
      }

   }
   //=======================================================
}
```

Comment: Your `checkanswer(boolean)` isn't behaving how you are probably expecting it to. Also, `if (tester = true) {` is not what you think either.

Comment: I'll help you out a little more `if(tester=true)` will always be true.  `=` is the assignment operator, not the equality operator which is `==`.  You therefore assign true to tester, and check if it is true.  However, by convention and to aid readability, you should simply do this `if(tester)`  You will also get more help if you correctly format your code (indentation).  It is very hard to follow as you have it and therefore people don't bother to try.  You must make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Indentation is your friend